# How to implement pre-rendering in Blazor WASM

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Blazor WASM with Prerendering gives error when clicking on Sign In link.

I added the following in Startup.cs:

```
    services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    services.AddScoped<SignOutSessionStateManager>();
```

https://github.com/jonasarcangel/PrerenderWithAuth/blob/master/PrerenderWithAuth/Server/Startup.cs

This was suggested in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15253. Other changes were also taken from https://jonhilton.net/blazor-wasm-prerendering/.

This is the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ServerAuthenticationStateProvider'
> to type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IRemoteAuthenticationService`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState]'.

UPDATE: I'm trying this, but I don't know what to put within each implementation.

```
public class HybridAuthenticationStateProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider, IRemoteAuthenticationService<RemoteAuthenticationState>
{
    public async Task<RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>> CompleteSignInAsync(RemoteAuthenticationContext<RemoteAuthenticationState> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public async Task<RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>> CompleteSignOutAsync(RemoteAuthenticationContext<RemoteAuthenticationState> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public async Task<RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>> SignInAsync(RemoteAuthenticationContext<RemoteAuthenticationState> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public async Task<RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>> SignOutAsync(RemoteAuthenticationContext<RemoteAuthenticationState> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't ServerAuthenticationStateProvider meant for Server side Blazor - it is in the Server namespace - why are you trying to use it in Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: I'm following a suggestion mentioned here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15253

Comment: Oh, I see I didn't spot the pre-rendering, so the code you included is in the host startup? That issue suggests that you need different services registered for auth when it is prerendering (on the server it requires Server auth) and when the client is interactive (it requires remote auth) - the error suggests you don't have both cases covered

Comment: I am creating a HybridAuthenticationStateProvider class, but I don't know what to put in each implementation.

Comment: @Jonas Arcangel, what are you doing... The error proves only that you've got an issue in your code, and it may not be related to ServerAuthenticationStateProvider at all. I don't think there is an issue with this object. I ran your code, and got 505 errors, so I'm going to create a fresh sample of the app.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me changing the title of your question, so that future users will benefit from it

Answer (score 7):

Client Side

remove the wwwroot/index.html file

### Program.Main

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("PrerenderWithAuth.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("PrerenderWithAuth.ServerAPI"));

            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

Note this: `builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");`
"app" is without '#'

### Server Side

### Pages/_Host.cshtml

```
@page "/"

@namespace PrerenderWithAuth.Server.Pages

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>PrerenderWithAuth</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="PrerenderWithAuth.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    @*<div id="app">Loading...</div>*@

    <app>
        @if (!HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/authentication"))
        {
            <component type="typeof(PrerenderWithAuth.Client.App)" render-mode="Static" />
            
        }
        else
        {
            <text>Loading...</text>
            
        }
    </app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### PrerenderWithAuth.Server/_Imports.razor

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using PrerenderWithAuth
@using PrerenderWithAuth.Shared
```

### Startup class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using PrerenderWithAuth.Server.Data;
using PrerenderWithAuth.Server.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace PrerenderWithAuth.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Added by me
            services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>(options => options.RootDirectory = "/Pages");
            // Added by me
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            // Added by me
            services.AddScoped<SignOutSessionStateManager>();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

           
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();



            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
               
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                //  endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked. The key fix was in _Host.html. That use of condition and Static render-mode works. The instruction in https://jonhilton.net/blazor-wasm-prerendering/ which used WebAssemblyPrerendered doesn't.